# what does “it is to+ sth（a noun）” mean? Is it a common usage of “to” to be followed by a noun?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've read a sentence in the Economist. And the sentence is

> "If Mr Rajapaska falls **it will not be to a** popular rising but because of anger at rising prices, corruption and one-family rule."

I'm having trouble understanding the usage and the meaning of "it will not be to a ...". Is there a usage of " it is to" followed by a noun? And also, what does the former half of this sentence mean?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I agree with @Frangipanes, but here's something simpler: *If Mr. R falls it will not be due to a popular uprising.*  Mine isn't as precise but I think it works.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fairly common usage. Usually as "If *X*, it will not be to *Y*" to indicate that *X* is more likely to happen for a some reason other than *Y*.

So in your sentence, *X* is *Mr Rajapaska falling*, and *Y* is *a popular uprising*:

*Mr Rajapaska is more likely to fall* [I assume this is fall as in "fall from power"?] *from* [public] *anger at rising prices, corruption and one-family rule than if there is a popular uprising* [against him]*.*

Does this help?